# How to check if the file system is case-sensitive on Windows, Mac, and Linux?

Tags: filesystems

What's a good way to check if my file system is case-sensitive (with file names) on Windows, Mac, and Linux?

Comment: Aside from reading the doco, do you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a script that enumerates some files, change the case on the filenames, then see if those new filenames exist (without modifying any files or writing anything to the filesystem). If they do, the filesystem is not case-sensitive.  I would check a number of files in case there happens to be both "myfile" and "MYFILE" in the same directory.

Comment: Actually, you'd need to check that *both* files exist.  NTFS is case-preserving, but the win32 subsystem is case-insensitive.  So a rename would work and the filename would be changed, but if you tried to create a different file with the same name with different cases, it would fail or overwrite (depending on what you asked for).

Comment: Right - if both files exist, then the filesystem is not case-sensitive.  If a file exists on NTFS with the name "myfile" and I check for the existence of "MYFILE", it will say that the file exists (the first step in my solution is to enumerate some files, so a check on the originals would be redundant).

Answer (score 10):

A simpler way to do this is run: `touch canCase && touch cancase` and then check if two or one files were created. If one file is created, your OS is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

As of Windows 10 1803, you can enable case sensitivity on NTFS partitions per directory.  Granted, this is uncommon (for now), but it complicates any sort of test you might concoct:

1. You can no longer just assume that Windows is case blind.
2. You have to test for the particular directory you care about.  (And, in theory, the answer can change an instant after you get your result.)
3. If the directory you need to test is read-only, then the try-it-and-see approach won't work.

Comment: This information needs more visibility.